# Docker - Cron unable to access file despite absolute paths in crontab

Tags: docker, cron

Why would crontab not be able to access the file /code/script.py in this scenario? When I manually inspect the Docker container by docker exec -it script_container sh I can see that the file exists.

error

```
/usr/local/bin/python: can't open file '/code/script.py\r': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /code/script.py
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:slim

WORKDIR /code
COPY files/requirements.txt .
COPY files/script.py .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#Cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

COPY files/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Additionally, I'm not able to see the stdout inside docker logs, even when I redirect the output from the crontab with

```
/proc/1/fd/1 2>&1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your file has DOS-style line endings and cron is trying to include a carriage return character `\r` as part of the script filename.

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the issue. :)